# No adapter attached; skipping layout : Recyclerview & Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I'm getting a weird error where my console states I am not attaching an adapter to my Recycler view.

As you can see from the code I am initializing it and calling for it to be used.

Any help would be appreciated

```
 //Variables + Widgets
String shareBody = "This is a Great App, TENCIL APP COMING SOON";
Button btnShare;
ImageView menuIcon;
LinearLayout contentView;
static float END_SCALE = 0.7f;
RecyclerView categoriesRecycler, featuredRecycler;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
//Drawer Menu
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
Context mContext;
//List for Array
List<Categories> categoriesList;
List<Businesses> businessesList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );


    setContentView ( R.layout.userdashboard );

    //Hooks
    menuIcon = findViewById ( R.id.menu_icon );
    contentView = findViewById ( R.id.content );
    categoriesRecycler = findViewById ( R.id.categories_recycler );
    featuredRecycler = findViewById ( R.id.featured_recycler );
    //Starting to create List
    categoriesList = new ArrayList<> ();
    businessesList = new ArrayList<> ();




    //RETROFIT

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder ()
            .baseUrl ( "https://providencewebservices.co.uk/api-test/v1/" )
            .addConverterFactory ( GsonConverterFactory.create () )
            .build ();

    UserService userService = retrofit.create ( UserService.class );

    Call<JSONResponse> call = userService.getCategories ();
    call.enqueue ( new Callback<JSONResponse> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call2, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body ();
            categoriesList = new ArrayList<> ( Arrays.asList ( jsonResponse.getCategories ()   ) );
            PutDataIntoRecyclerView ( categoriesList );


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call2, Throwable t) {

        }
    } );



    Call<FeaturedResponse> call2 = userService.getFeaturedinc ();
    call2.enqueue ( new Callback<FeaturedResponse> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FeaturedResponse> call2, Response<FeaturedResponse> response) {

            FeaturedResponse featuredResponse = response.body ();
            businessesList = new ArrayList<> ( Arrays.asList ( featuredResponse.getBusinesses ()   ) );
            PutDataIntoRecyclerViewFeatured ( businessesList );


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FeaturedResponse> call2, Throwable t) {

        }
    } );



    //Menu Hooks
    drawerLayout = findViewById ( R.id.drawer_layout );
    navigationView = findViewById ( R.id.navigation_view );
    menuIcon = findViewById ( R.id.menu_icon );

    //RecyclerView Hooks
    contentView = findViewById ( R.id.content );
    navigationDrawer ();


}

private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<Categories> categoriesList) {
    CategoriesAdapter categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter (this, categoriesList);
    categoriesRecycler.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false ) );
    categoriesRecycler.setAdapter ( categoriesAdapter );

}
private void PutDataIntoRecyclerViewFeatured(List<Businesses> businessesList) {
    FeatureAdapter featureAdapter = new FeatureAdapter ( this, businessesList );
    featuredRecycler.setHasFixedSize ( true );
    featuredRecycler.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false )  );
    featuredRecycler.setAdapter ( featureAdapter );
    Toast.makeText ( this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
}
```

Featured Adapter for retrofit

```
public class FeatureAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<FeatureAdapter.FeaturedViewHolder>{

private Context gContext;
private List<Businesses> gData;


public FeatureAdapter(Context gContext, List<Businesses> gData) {
    this.gContext = gContext;
    this.gData = gData;
}

//Returns Featured View Dynamically
public FeatureAdapter.FeaturedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    gContext = parent.getContext ();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from ( gContext ).inflate ( R.layout.featured_card_design, parent, false );
    return new FeatureAdapter.FeaturedViewHolder ( view );
}


public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeaturedViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.business_name.setText ( gData.get ( position ).getBusiness_name () );
holder.bdesc.setText ( gData.get ( position ).getBdesc () );

}

public int getItemCount() {
    return gData.size ();
}

//HOLDS VIEWS
public class FeaturedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout featuredcard;
    TextView business_name;
    TextView bdesc;


    public FeaturedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );
        //HOOKS
        featuredcard = itemView.findViewById ( featured_card );
        business_name = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.featured_title );
        bdesc = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.featured_desc );





    }


}
```

}

I will attach a screenshot of my current app with a working recycler view

[My END Goal is to have 2/3 of my recycler views working so any help is greatly appreciated]

Grey = Working

RED = Not

[image]

CONSOLE ERROR

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: it's clearly not attaching the adapter into your Feature RV for some reason. The only difference I noticed in your methods was `featuredRecycler.setHasFixedSize ( true );` , could the error have something to do with that? 

Try commenting out the call to `PutDataIntoRecyclerViewFeatured()` and see if you are still getting the error. Maybe you can work from there.

Comment: Hi, I will try that and let you know shortly

Comment: Hey @panosGr, Issue still occurring unfortunately

Comment: Try setting up your recyclerViews before the Retrofit calls and use an `updateList()` method inside the adapters that updates the list.

Comment: @PanosGr can you advise me on how I would do that? The issue is still occurring after trying multiple ways of calling it